# Как узнать завершился ли пул потоков ExecutorService?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Доброго времени суток.
Есть код:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            executorService.execute(new ParallelRunnable(parallelGraph, parallelLineData, i));
    }
```

Он создает пулл потоков.
Вопрос такой: как отловить завершение всех потоков этого екзекутора и по завершению выполнить код.
Действия происходят на андроид.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самый топорный метод - ожидание остановки пула:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    executorService.execute(new ParallelRunnable(parallelGraph, parallelLineData, i));
}
taskExecutor.shutdown();
try {
    taskExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    // Здесь выполнить действие
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    ...
}
```

Более разумный метод - это координировать завершение работы внутри самих задач:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    executorService.execute(() -> {
        try {
            // Выполнение задачи
            latch.countDown();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    });
}
latch.await();
// Здесь выполнить действие
```

А самый толковый, на мой взгляд - это использовать CompletableFuture:

```
ComplatableFuture<Void>[] futures = new ComplatableFuture<>[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    futures[i] = CompletableFuture.runAsync(new ParallelRunnable(parallelGraph, parallelLineData, i), executorService);
}
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures)
                 .thenRun(() -> {
                     // Здесь выполнить действие
                 });
```